# how to show error message when session time out glassfish security?

Tags: java, jsf, session, glassfish

I am using Glassfish security with Realm for my J2ee project using jsf . My session time out in 30 min.

when i click on component  it is redirecting to the login page thats good.

but u want before that the user click on the component when the session is out a dialog or msg need to apear to alarm user that the session is expired .

thats why i tried this way but didnt work using jsf listener :

```
<f:event listener="#{Logincontroller.checksessiontimeout}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

and in the managed been :

```
public void checksessiontimeout(ComponentSystemEvent event) 
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)             context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        if (request.getRequestedSessionId()!=null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid())
        { 
            System.out.println("Session Log OUT");
        }
    }
```

but when the session is time out didnt print nothing for me thats prove the function didnt work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use OmniFaces, how about using an idleMonitor to check the session status every x milliseconds?
The below will fire when the user comes back to the web page after being away for 5 minutes.  The only problem is it won't fire if the user sits there moving the mouse around the web page without actually doing anything, but the session would still timeout.

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="18000000">
<p:ajax event="active" listener="#{Logincontroller.checksessiontimeout}" />
</p:idleMonitor>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer just want to know how much 18000000 = 18 minut ??

Comment: Oops, I think it's in milliseconds, 18,000,000 so that's 18,000 seconds or 5 hours.  So 5 minutes would be 5*60*1000=300,000.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an error message to the user, I suggest you do this with javascript. I think that System.out.println will just print a line to your Glassfish's console.

Try putting this as error message:

```
out.print("<script>alert(\"Session timed out!\");</script>");
```

Comment: yes i want just be visible in glassfish for test before implementing new code ... just to verify that my function is called

Comment: Look, if I were you, I would set a maximum interval with session.setMaxInactiveInterval(...), and set a status attribute, like: 
session.setAttribute("status", "active");
Then, for each page, I would check if session was active, like this:
<% if(session.getAttribute("status")==null){ out.print(user_error); System.out.println(server_error); out.print(redirect_usr);}%>

Comment: i need a listener in all page that call a function when the session time out.

Comment: but the problem the session is down how i can then show a message ??